# Progress bar in command-line R

Tags: r

I am attempting to use a progress bar in an R script for command-line, however it only shows 0%. Please consider the following working example:

```
 testit <- function(x = sort(runif(20)), ...)
 {
     pb <- txtProgressBar(...)
     for(i in c(0, x, 1)) {Sys.sleep(0.5); setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)}
     Sys.sleep(1)
     close(pb)
 }
 testit()
 testit(runif(10))
 testit(style = 3)
```

My code, however, does not work accordingly, and I am failing to identify my error:

```
  dep=c("data.table", "docopt")
  for (i in dep){
    pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(dep), style = 3)
    if (i %in% installed.packages()){
      library(i, character.only = TRUE)
    } else {
      install.packages(i, repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies = T)
      library(i, character.only = TRUE)
    }
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
  }
  close(pb)
```

- How to make the progress bar actually progress in the latter?

Comment: `setTxtProgressBar` needs it's second argument to be a number between 0 and 1. The `i` you are giving it is first `"data.table"`, then `"docopt"`.

Comment: I see, how can I pass the iteration value for i?

Comment: Do something like `fraction_done = match(i, dep) / length(dep)` and then do `setTxtProgressBar(pb, fraction_done)`. Or rewrite your loop with `for (i in seq_along(dep))` so `i` will be 1, 2, 3, ... and you can use `setTxtProgressBar(pb, i / length(dep))`, but you'll need to replace all your other `i` values with `dep[i]`.

Comment: Assign `pb` *before* the `for` loop starts, not within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comments were basically an answer, so:

`setTxtProgressBar` needs it's second argument to be a number between 0 and 1. The `i` you are giving it is first `"data.table"`, then `"docopt"`.

The quickest way to modify your code to work would be to compute how far along you are each iteration. Add to your loop:

```
fraction_done = match(i, dep) / length(dep)
setTxtProgressBar(pb, fraction_done)
```

And in this case, we're computing the fraction so you can use the default `1` as the progress bar length.

An option I prefer is to rewrite your loop with so that `i` will be `1, 2, 3, ...`. While R lets you loop over arbitrary values, it can lead to confusion like in your question. Instead, I almost always loop over 1, 2, 3, .... Sometimes it takes a little more typing, but it's clear and consistent. In this case:

```
dep=c("data.table", "docopt")
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(dep), style = 3)

for (i in seq_along(dep)){
  if (!dep[i] %in% installed.packages()){
    install.packages(dep[i], repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies = T)
  }
  library(dep[i], character.only = TRUE)
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}
close(pb)
```

I also simplified the structure a little bit (the `else` isn't really needed if you switch the `if` around). And, as pointed out in the comments, you want to start the bar before loop, not every time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: `i` is a `character` and not a number; and you are re-assigning to `pb` each time in your loop. Gregor's suggestion to keep `i` an integer (my preferred of his two suggestions) could be implemented like this:

```
dep=c("data.table", "docopt")
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(dep), style = 3)
for (i in seq_along(dep)){
  if (dep[i] %in% installed.packages()){
    library(dep[i], character.only = TRUE)
  } else {
    install.packages(dep[i], repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies = T)
    library(dep[i], character.only = TRUE)
  }
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}
close(pb)
```

(Untested, as I don't have your data.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `i` is a string, not an integer as in the first exmaple you gave, you might be looking more into something like

```
dep=c("data.table", "docopt")
for (i in seq_along(dep)){
  pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(dep), style = 3)
  if (dep[i] %in% installed.packages()){
    library(dep[i], character.only = TRUE)
  } else {
    install.packages(dep[i], repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies = T)
    library(dep[i], character.only = TRUE)
  }
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}
close(pb)
```

Comment: Many good answers posted at the same time Answered by Gregor's comments mostly. Votes should go to his solution :)

Comment: One more `i` needs changing to `dep[i]` in the `if()` test.